# IOException (end of stream) in "PUT" and "DELETE" Method in Retrofit

Tags: android, nginx, retrofit, retrofit2, ioexception

I have two method inside my `ApiClient` which I get Error `IOException` (end of stream), what is the problem?

Here is my code :

```
@PUT("api/v1/project/{id}")
Call<ResponseBody> updateProjectInfo(@Path("id") int id, @Body 
EditProjectModelData projectData);

@DELETE("api/v1/project/{id}")
Call<ResponseBody> deleteProject(@Path("id") int id);
```

> Error : java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{..}

Comment: exact issue is not clear by these lines of code

Comment: please provide more information like the exact error

Comment: @Distra Error : java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{..}

Comment: @DavidOli maybe you'll find the fix of your issue here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2738